# c++ Class -> Vector -> File

Tags: c++, vector

I have this requirement.

I am trying to make a simple database schema, a little different than what I have seen in here. I have a class file (client.h) with it's implementation (client.cpp):

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H_
#define CLIENT_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Client {
public:
    // constructors
    Client();
    Client(string new_name, string new_tel, string new_addr);
    // getters
    string getName();
    string getAddr();
    string getTel();
    // setters
    void setName(string);
    void setAddr(string);
    void setTel(string);
    void display();
    void input();
private:
    // fields
    string name;
    string addr;
    string tel;
};
#endif /* CLIENT_H_ */

/*
 *ad client.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 12, 2017
 *      Author: niksarid
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "client.h"
using namespace std;

Client::Client() {
    setName("");
    setAddr("");
    setTel("");
}

Client::Client(std::string new_name, std::string new_addr, std::string     new_tel) {
    setName(new_name);
    setAddr(new_addr);
    setTel(new_tel);
}

string Client::getName() {
    return name;
}

string Client::getAddr() {
    return addr;
}

string Client::getTel() {
    return tel;
}

void Client::setName(string p_name) {
    name = p_name;
}

void Client::setAddr(string p_addr) {
    addr = p_addr;
}

void Client::setTel(string p_tel) {
    tel = p_tel;
}

void Client::input() {
    string tmp;

    cout << "INPUT CLIENT INFO" << endl;
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> tmp;
    setName(tmp);
    cout << "Address: ";
    cin >> tmp;
    setAddr(tmp);
    cout  << "Telephone: ";
    cin >> tmp;
    setTel(tmp);
}

void Client::display() {
    cout << name << "\t" << addr << "\t" << tel << endl;
}
```

So I am trying to make a Company class that will hold a vector of Clients and at the startup of the program it will load the datafile "clients.dat", into the vector. I will be able to add a client or delete a client from the vector. At the end the vector will be saved back to "clients.dat".

So, the (company.h) file is like this:

```
class Company {
public:
    Company();
    ~Company();
    void add_client();
    void print_clients();
    void loadClientsFromFile();
    void saveClientsToFile();
private:
    vector<Client> clients;
} cmp;
#endif /* COMPANY_H_ */
```

but I can't seem to reference clients vector in any of the public methods of the class company.

EDIT: Sorry! Forgot the important part!! 
For example when I try to `add_client()`,

```
void add_client() {
    Client c;

    c.input();
    clients.push_back(c);
}
```

but I get 
../src/company.cpp:49:2: error: 'clients' was not declared in this scope
  clients.push_back(c);

So, how to achieve that?

Comment: Your problem description is not clear, do you get a compiler error?

Comment: What error do you get when trying to access the `clients` vector in `Company::print_clients()` for example?

Comment: Please provide the implementation code of the member functions of the Company class where you try to access the vector. Are you sure you haven't just forgotten to add Company:: as prefix to the function names in your company.cpp ?

Comment: Thank you MerlinND!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Morgan mentioned in the comments, this problem typically arises when you try to define the member function in your implementation file, but forget to add the class name as prefix (e.g. `void add_client() {}` instead of `void Company::add_client() {}`.

This mistake is common and can easily go unnoticed, since it is perfectly legal to define a new free function called `add_client` in your file, that would have nothing to do with the `Company` class. That's why the compiler only complains when you try to access a data member, but not before.